# Will the Windows 10 Free Upgrade stay in the Professional channel?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

When the free Windows 10 upgrade comes out, will you get the Pro version or Home version if you have Windows 8.1 Pro or Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you upgrade, you’ll stay on like-to-like editions of Windows. For example, Windows 7 Home Premium will upgrade to Windows 10 Home.

[image: Windows 10 Upgrade Options]

Source: [Windows 10 FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq)

Comment: Well, the names are the same, but what reason do we have to believe that the features are the same? For example, maybe something available in 7 Home Premium is now only available in 10 Pro and not 10 Home.

Comment: @fredsbend A good thought, but there are many previews, reviews, and feature lists showing that this is simply not the case. The only things not included in either edition that may be in W7 or W8 are on their specification list under 'Feature Deprecation':
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications